# Stop recently started container in docker?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

```
   docker stop lastContainerName
```

It works fine. I want to stop it using `docker ps -l` command

```
   docker stop | docker ps -l
```

I tried this. Unfortunately `docker stop --help` getting executed.

Am i missing something? How to achieve this? Any Suggestions.

Comment: Are you using Boot2Docker on Mac or on Windows?  They have different command-line syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to pipe the output of `docker ps -l` as an argument of the `docker stop` command.  One way to do this in Unix is with back-quotes:

```
docker stop `docker ps -lq`
```

(I also added a `-q` option so you get just the ID with no column-names, etc.)